# Clickhouse backup to disk problem < backups.allowed_disk configuration parameter is not set >

Tags: clickhouse

When I tried to backup a table to disk in clickhouse by the following:

```
BACKUP TABLE xxx.tb_log TO Disk('xxx.tb_log', 'test_20221007');
```

I faced this error:

> Code: 318. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: The 'backups.allowed_disk' configuration parameter is not set, cannot use 'Disk' backup engine. (INVALID_CONFIG_PARAMETER)

What should I do to backup a table in disk.

Comment: Did you configure the disk as shown here in the docs? https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/backup#backup-to-a-local-disk

Comment: No. Thank you Rich! It seems the cause of problem.